# JavaMail 1.4.2 supported TLSv1.2?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, tls1.2

as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638567/which-version-of-tls-is-supported-by-javamail-1-4) JavaMail 1.4 doesn't support to TLSv1.2, but how to know [JavaMail 1.4.2](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javamail-api.html) support TLSv1.2 or not?

Comment: For example I have code written 16 years ago that supports TLS 1.3 even though it wasn't even invented at the time. It would also support SSLv3 and even SSLv2 if Java did.

Comment: @BillShannon Would appreciate your comment on this urban myth.

Comment: See my new answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638567/which-version-of-tls-is-supported-by-javamail-1-4

Comment: @kyorilys On the contrary. The question is answered. Read what I wrote. There is nothing about proof in the question, and nothing to prove in the first place. And please note that the citation he is relying on for the validity of the question has been amended, downvoted, and voted for deletion.